# Date format query for next 12 months

Tags: sql-server, date-format

I'm trying to make a query regarding the date format YYYYMM. My current query is this one.

```
declare @M0 nvarchar(6);set @M0=(SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112))
declare @M1 nvarchar(6);set @M1=@M0+1;
declare @M2 nvarchar(6);set @M2=@M1+1;
declare @M3 nvarchar(6);set @M3=@M2+1;
declare @M4 nvarchar(6);set @M4=@M3+1;
declare @M5 nvarchar(6);set @M5=@M4+1;
declare @M6 nvarchar(6);set @M6=@M5+1;
declare @M7 nvarchar(6);set @M7=@M6+1;
declare @M8 nvarchar(6);set @M8=@M7+1;
declare @M9 nvarchar(6);set @M9=@M8+1;
declare @M10 nvarchar(6);set @M10=@M9+1;
declare @M11 nvarchar(6);set @M11=@M10+1;
declare @M12 nvarchar(6);set @M12=@M11+1;
select @M0,@M1,@M2,@M3,@M4,@M5,@M6,@M7,@M8,@M9,@M10,@M11,@M12
```

What I'm trying to get is from the current date the next 12 months in YYYYMM date format. But with my current query is giving: 201705,201706,...201711,201712,201713,201714, and so on. So by now you might already know what I'm trying to get is: 201705,201706,...201711,201712,201801,201802, and so on.

I've searched almost trough all the web, and have found no answer. So I've come here so hopefully someone could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of SQL Server's `DATEADD` which will handle rolling over to the next year and resetting back to January, then convert that to your YYYYMM format, like this:

```
DECLARE @M0 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112 );
DECLARE @M1 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 1, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M2 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 2, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M3 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 3, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M4 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 4, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M5 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 5, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M6 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 6, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M7 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 7, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M8 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 8, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M9 NVARCHAR(6)  = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 9, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M10 NVARCHAR(6) = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 10, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M11 NVARCHAR(6) = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 11, GETDATE() ), 112 );
DECLARE @M12 NVARCHAR(6) = CONVERT( NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD( MONTH, 12, GETDATE() ), 112 );
SELECT @M0, @M1, @M2, @M3, @M4, @M5, @M6, @M7, @M8, @M9, @M10, @M11, @M12
```

The output is:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 201705 | 201706 | 201707 | 201708 | 201709 | 201710 | 201711 | 201712 | 201801 | 201802 | 201803 | 201804 | 201805 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if you feel it has resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Handy little snippet as I can never remember the codes...

```
        WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
            ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
            ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
            ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
            ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv3)
        SELECT  CAST( n AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' - ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),GETDATE(), n) xZample
        , 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@MindIfWeDanceWitYoDates, '+CAST(n AS VARCHAR(25))+')' AS  _________________________tehcode____________________________
        FROM Tally
        WHERE (n< 200) AND (n%100 IN (0,20,21,120,121,126,127,130,131) OR n%100 <= 14)
        ORDER BY n;
```